# $S^2 / (\text{pseudo-circle}) \approx S^2 \vee S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The below is a statement in Bredon's Topology and Geometry.

> [image]
>
> [image]

My question is why $X/A \approx S^2 \vee S^2 $.
I have checked that two parts partitioned by the arc are open sets and not contaied in the same component. But I have no idea for homeomorphism.
How to show that $X/A \approx S^2 \vee S^2 $?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each component of $X\setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (you can prove this directly with a little work, but a sledgehammer way to prove it is to note that they are both contractible and so the Riemann mapping theorem gives not just a homeomorphism but a biholomorphism to an open disk).  Let $U$ and $V$ be the two components of $X\setminus A$.  Note that the image of $U\cup A$ in $X/A$ is then compact Hausdorff and when you remove one point (the image of $A$) you get a space homeomorphic to $U$, so it is a one-point compactification of $U$.  Thus the image of $U\cup A$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$, and similarly for $V\cup A$.  This gives a continuous bijection $S^2\vee S^2\to X/A$, which is a homeomorphism since the domain is compact and the codomain is Hausdorff.